# jQuery .click event not Working

Tags: jquery-ui

Here is script I used

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: true,
    height: 300,
    width: 350,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
      'Calling': function(){},
      'Cancel' :  function(){
        $(this).dialog('close');
      }
    }
  });

  $('#id_call').click(function() {
    $("#dialog").dialog("open");
  });
});
</script>
```

In this one button is used to show the dialog

```
<button id="id_call">Click to Call</button>
```

But click event is not working...

Comment: Can we see the appropriate bit of the markup?  Is the dialog just failing to open, or is the click event not firing at all?

Answer (score 0):

Can you bind the event like this instead?

```
$('#id_call').bind('click', function() { $("#dialog").dialog("open"); });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this: http://jsfiddle.net/K2C4n/

I changed `autoOpen: false`

HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>        
    <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>

  <button id="id_call">Click to Call</button>

  <div id="dialog" title="Dialog Title">I'm in a dialog</div>

</body>
</html>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#dialog").dialog({
autoOpen: false,
height: 300,
width: 350,
modal: true,
buttons: {
  'Calling': function(){},
  'Cancel' :  function(){
    $(this).dialog('close');
  }
  }
  });

 $('#id_call').click(function() {
   $("#dialog").dialog("open");
 });
});
```

EDIT: Don't forget to include jQuery and jQueryUI.

Comment: Works well, but even if you change it to `autoOpen: true` it still seems to work (albeit on load as well)!

Comment: It makes a different if you change autoOpen to true or false. If true, the dialog appears immediatly and if false the dialogs appears only when the button is clicked.

Comment: Agreed, but even if set to true it still works on click as well, so potentially not the problem @ashok is experiencing?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible you may have another HTML node with the same ID?  jQuery essentially uses .getElementyById() which only returns one node for that ID regardless of how many nodes have that particular ID.